# Which reaction is useful to prepare odd number of hydrocarbons?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

Which reaction is useful to prepare odd number of hydrocarbons:

1. Wurtz reaction
2. Kolbe electrolysis
3. Corey–House synthesis
4. Oxymercuration

Wurtz reaction produces even products except if we take mixtures. Kolbe ones give even ones too. Oxymercuration merely involves addition, so I think it's Corey–House.

But how does one justify that exactly? Is it because of $\ce{Cu(CH3)2Li}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite correct. Wurtz works best (and even that isn't great) when dimerising, same for Kolbe (which works better). Oyxymercuration functionalises a double bond but does not introduce alkyl groups. Corey-House works particularly well with Me for extending the chain by one unit, but also works for propyl, pentyl etc as well as benzyl.

Answer (score 2):

> The Corey–House reaction constitutes a general and high yielding method for the joining of two alkyl groups or an alkyl group and an aryl group.

- Step one involves preparation of the Gilman reagent from an alkyl halide.

$$\ce{R–X + 2Li -> RLi + Li+X–}$$

- Second step, a lithium dialkylcuprate (Gilman reagent) is prepared from the alkyllithium by treatment with cuprous iodide (CuI).

$$\ce{2RLi + CuI -> Li+[R–Cu–R]– + LiI}$$

- The third step ,involvs reaction between lithium dialkylcuprate (Gilman reagent) and a second alkyl halide ,resulting in the formation of a C–C bond between the two organic fragments:

$$\ce{Li+[R–Cu–R]– + R'–X -> R–R' + "RCu" + LiX}$$

**Example 1**

In the following example, gem dihalides react with $\ce{Li+[CH_3–Cu–CH_3]– }$ to give the final product. You could read about it in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey%E2%80%93House_synthesis)

[image]

**Example 2**

[image]

[source](https://www.synarchive.com/named-reactions/corey-posner-whitesides-house-reaction)

**Reference**

1.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey%E2%80%93House_synthesis

2.https://www.synarchive.com/named-reactions/corey-posner-whitesides-house-reaction